# Append the parameter to the name of table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to write a procedure in which month wise data is collected and stored in a table. So what I want to do is append the name of the month which is passed as a parameter to the name of the table.

--This is the procedure that I have written.

```
CREATE procedure month_data(IN month varchar(20))
BEGIN

declare monthName varchar(255);

set @monthName := concat('CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS monthName_"',month,'"
select * from dup_activity_log where monthname(cur_date)="',month,'";');
prepare stmt from @monthName;
execute stmt;

END //
```

/* I am getting a runtime syntax error in this but I am not sure what I should do to remove it. I am fairly new to MySQL, so thanks in advance for helping. */

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '"June" select * from dup_activity_log where
>   monthname(cur_date)="June"' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some unnecessary double quotes surrounding part of the table name. And there should be a space between the table name and the start of the select. Try this (`''` is treated as a single quote embedded in the string):

```
set @sql := concat(
    'CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS monthName_',
    month,
    ' select * from dup_activity_log where monthname(cur_date) = ''',
    month,
    ''';'
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I removed the double quotes near the table name rest same,

Answer (score 0):

It's better that you use parameter placeholder `?` for `WHERE` clause instead of playing with quotes:

```
SET @sql = concat(
  'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS monthName_', month,
  ' SELECT * FROM dup_activity_log WHERE monthname(cur_date) = ?'  
  );
```

And then when you are executing it pass the parameter:

```
EXECUTE stmt USING @month;
```

See the full code outside of procedure:

```
SET @month = monthname(curdate());   
SET @sql = concat(
  'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS monthName_', @month,
  ' SELECT * FROM dup_activity_log WHERE monthname(cur_date) = ?'  
  );                    
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING @month;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I didn't know about it before but I will try it now. Thanks.